# When I Add many Items into ListBox, I get OutOfMemoryException . How to modify it?

Tags: windows-phone-7

this is my ListBox:

XMLA:

```
<Style x:Key="ListBoxStyle" TargetType="ListBox">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Disabled"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBox">
                    <ScrollViewer x:Name="ScrollViewer">
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="{TemplateBinding Height}"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="100"/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <ItemsPresenter Grid.Row="0"/>
                            <Button Content="Add" Grid.Row="1" Click="Button_Click"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </ScrollViewer>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>  <ListBox Style="{StaticResource ListBoxStyle}" Name="listBox" Height="600" ItemsSource="{Binding MyData}">
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                            <Image Source="{Binding Img}" Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
```

Code-Behind:

```
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
        {
            MyData.Add(new Data { Name = i.ToString(), Img = "/Background.png" });
        }
    }
```

When I Click Button more, I get a OutOfMemoryException.

but,If I don't set ListBox Style. I add Items into ListBox,the Project is Work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you retemplate the `ListBox`, you lose data virtualization. So, all your item images are in memory all the time. Can you decrease the size of the images to avoid high memory consumption?

Comment: Oh. My ListBox must have images. Can you tell me how to retemplate my ListBox and not lose data virtualization ?

Comment: One of the ways you can do this: delete "More" `Button` and detect bottom compression state to load next items

Comment: I find a solution user Scrollviewer and itemsControl to compose a ListBox

Comment: @Ku6opr I thought that Virtualization is achieved through VirtualizingStackPanel, it has nothing to do with retemplate ??

Answer (score 0):

I suppose, to enable virtualization you should change ListBox ControlTemplate. Move all except of ItemsPresenter out of ScrollViewer:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBox">
  <Grid>
     <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition Height="100"/>
     </Grid.RowDefinitions>
     <ScrollViewer x:Name="ScrollViewer" Grid.Row="0">
          <ItemsPresenter />
     </ScrollViewer>
     <Button Content="Add" Grid.Row="1" Click="Button_Click"/>
  </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>
```

And make sure that your MyData implements IList interface.

Comment: MyData implement IList interface.

Comment: Move all except of ItemsPresenter out of ScrollViewer . the virtualization is disable still

Comment: in such case, perhaps it worth using default ControlTemplate for ListBox and place 'Add' button near the ListBox.
Thanks for posting this issue, it's important to be aware of such limitations. I've never read about that before.

Comment: if edit ListBox 's Style , The ListBox virtualization disable http://www.eugenedotnet.com/2011/05/itemscontrol-virtualization-using-virtualizingstackpanel-in-silverlight-for-windows-phone-7/sable.